# Have a user crop an image

Tags: android, bitmap, crop

I Currently have it where a user pics an image from gallery. It is then converted to a bitmap and displayed in a imageview and sent to my server. The way I currently have it being cropped is bellow. However, I want the user to have a 300x300 box they can move around and when they press upload it will upload what is within that 300x300 view

```
 if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()){

                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            bitmap,
                            0,
                            0,
                            bitmap.getHeight(),
                            bitmap.getHeight()
                    );

                }else{

                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            bitmap,
                            0,
                            0,
                            bitmap.getWidth(),
                            bitmap.getWidth()
                    );
                }
```

This is my first application so I am still earning the ropes. Thank you for your time and patience ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample function to crop a image of desired size.Please do  check it.you can call this 'performCrop()' function from onActivityResult().

```
public void performCrop() {

        try {
            // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
            // support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(selectedImageUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 300); //your desired size here 
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 300); //your desired size here
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            File f = createNewFile("CROP_");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {

            }

            CropImagedUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, CropImagedUri);

            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            // display an error message
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                PerformCrop();
                // Img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {
                CropImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(CropImagedUri);
            }
}
```